# How to write bitbucket pipeline correctly with rsync?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsync, bitbucket-pipelines

I am writing a bitbucket pipeline to deploy my angular project to the ec2 instance. This is my pipeline using rsync.

```yaml
image: node:12.18.3
pipelines:
    branches:
      dev:
      - step:
         name: Build Test Environment
         caches:
           - node
         script:
           - npm install
           - npm run build-qa
         artifacts:
            - dist/qa/**
         deployment: test
      - step:
              name: Deploy
              trigger: manual
              script:
                - apt-get update && apt-get install -y rsync
                - ssh-keyscan -H $SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                - cd $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist/qa
                - ls
                - rsync -v -e ssh . $SSH_USER@$SERVER:/var/www/html/myproject
                - echo "Deployment is done...!"
```

But this is giving me this error.

```
+ rsync -v -e ssh . $SSH_USER@$SERVER:/var/www/html/myproject
skipping directory .
rsync: link_stat "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/qa/$SSH_USER@myip" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/qa/ecdsa-sha2-nistp256" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir#3 "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/qa//AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNtYTItbmlzdHAyNTwAAqAIbmlzdHAyNsYAAABBBGqKvzLI7IolhgM1ZEfol3VuJX4CX6jzqSyM6AzUgPbpyERywu/7U/SioMc/SLeJyfhYnWAJVApt8oOsqIjLqDg=:/var/www/html/myproject" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(713) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

I tried a lot to find out a solution to this I even tried with the rsync-deploy pipe but it also gives the same above error can someone help me to write this pipeline correctly to get my requirement done?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do cd and ls in a script, but looking at the error, your path is wrong. The remote path should be something like /var/www/websitename, not your bitbucket. I'd investigate what your directory structure actually looks like in your EC2 and use that instead of $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR. $REMOTE_DESTINATION_PATH might work, but again I'm not sure what your setup is.

Comment: @AMR I added cd and ls just to check what are the files available.

Answer (score 0):

Seems similar to the issue here https://serverfault.com/questions/363555/why-is-rsync-skipping-the-main-directory

- you probably have folders inside you want to recursively include in the transfer
- you need to change the source to ./ so it gets it is a folder

and as a bonus

- you can/should just run ls with the path, and same with rsync, and not cd into there. Remember the trailing /